# Setting an IP address to a TUN in C

Tags: c, network-programming, ioctl, tun

I'm trying to create a tunnel in C and im struggling to set its IP address up. I have an "invalid argument" error in ioctl with SIOCSIFADDR argument. Can someone explain me how to set up the IP address if this function doesn't work with tun ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/if_tun.h>
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>


#define IP_DEST "127.0.0.1"
#define IP_SOURCE "127.0.0.1"



int tun_alloc(char* dev) {
    //dev will store the name of the tun created

    struct ifreq ifr;
    int fd, err;
    char *clonedev = "/dev/net/tun";

    //open the clone device 
    if( (fd = open(clonedev, O_RDWR)) < 0 ) {
        printf("Error opening directory");
        return fd;
    }

    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TUN;  
    if (*dev) {
     strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, dev, IFNAMSIZ);
   }

    //Create the TUN
    if( (err = ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *) &ifr)) < 0 ) {
        close(fd);
        printf("Error creating the tun");
        return err;
    }
    strcpy(dev, ifr.ifr_name);

    return fd;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    //Creating the TUN interface
    char tun_name[IFNAMSIZ];
    strncpy(tun_name, "tun3", IFNAMSIZ);

    int tunfd = tun_alloc(tun_name);
    if (tunfd < 0) {
        perror("tun_create");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("TUN interface %s created\n", tun_name);

    //Setting its IP Adress
    struct ifreq ifr;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, tun_name, IFNAMSIZ);

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET,IP_DEST,&(addr.sin_addr))<0){
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR with the IP address");
        return 1;
    };

    memcpy(&(ifr.ifr_addr), &addr, sizeof (struct sockaddr));
    if (ioctl(tunfd, SIOCSIFADDR, &ifr) < 0) {
        perror("ioctl");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("TUN interface %s set IP address to %s\n", tun_name, IP_DEST);

    ifr.ifr_flags |= IFF_UP | IFF_RUNNING;
    if(ioctl(tunfd, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifr)<0){
        perror("ioctl");
        exit(1);
    };
    printf("TUN running");
    return 0;
}
```

I don't really understand how iotcl works and the documentation hasn't helped me for tun interfaces.

Comment: Yeah, I'm with you.  The only good "documentation" I've been able to find is on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The `SIOCSIFADDR` and `SIOCSIFFLAGS` (and other `SIOwhatever`) `ioctl` calls should be made towards any `AF_INET` socket, not towards the `tun` interface itself. The design is so that you can use them to configure *any* interface, not only the one you created. You have to create an `AF_INET` socket and then call `ioctl` on that socket.

If you think it's a bit weird that you have to make a socket, you're right. `ioctl` is used to make "special requests" about files, other than `read` or `write`. The request is interpreted depending on the type of file. Using a socket makes sure it is interpreted by the IP networking system as a request relating to IP sockets. It *would* make logical sense that you could also make IP-related special requests on `tun` interfaces, but apparently the kernel developers didn't think of that, and there is no need for them to work since you can just create a socket.

There is another way to set IP addresses using a system called "rtnetlink", but it is more complicated and unnecessary for a simple scenario like this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but how to "link" the socket to the 'tun' interface? I mean how will it change the ip adress of the 'tun' interface ?

Comment: @AntoineBourgeois there is no linking

Comment: ok but then how do i set the ip adress of the tun ?

Comment: @AntoineBourgeois you create a socket and you use ioctl with SIOCSIFADDR